# Turning off $routeprovider when using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some normal routeprovider code, but in a certain section of my HTML I have some twitter bootstrap expand/collapse sections. Clicking on them triggers the routeprovider, which I don't want to do. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/projects', {
      templateUrl: 'project.html',
      controller: 'projectController'
    });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

A section of the HTML

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                              Open Projects
                          </a>
                      </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table id="openProjectTable" class="table">
                            <tr><th>Project</th><th>Source</th><th>Target</th></tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the html/bootstrap code?

Comment: Ok, but it doesn't add much. When clicking the "Open Projects" link, it will refresh the page as I said.

Comment: Maybe you should switch to [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I suppose `href="#collapseOne"` is detected as route change. This should not happen when you use UI Bootstrap correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use **data-target** instead of **href**:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
  Open Projects
</a>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OYEeUd6hAJE0hBBJOrp7?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest way to implement it.